# How to open the index.html after every test automatically

Tags: java, report, rest-assured, serenity-bdd

I am using Serenity BDD with Rest Assured and want to open the latest index.html report automatically.

Using below code but it doesn't open the latest report.
what changes needs to be done to get the latest report?

```
@AfterClass
public static void getReportAutomatically() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        // WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        WebDriver driver = Serenity.getDriver();
        driver.get("C:/Users/name/Desktop/My-Den/IntelliJ Projects/Restassured-Serenity

}
```

Comment: `it doesn't open the latest report` --> what does it mean?

Comment: Its not providing me the current or updated test run report

Comment: How do you run the test?

Comment: mvn clean install - we use this command

Comment: I don't think you can get what you want. From my understanding, `AfterClass` will be run in `integration-test` phase. And report is in `post-integration-test` phase. Therefore, never get the latest version of report